# Django DatabaseError - What is the best way to debug?

Tags: database, django, admin

I'm having some trouble with a django database (postgresql backend).There was a model (a profile for users) in the project with some boilerplate stuff in it.  This has sat in our project for a while, not being used.  I actually got round to needing this, so I adjusted the models and created some initial migrations with South.  On my dev box I dropped the entire db and syncdb'ed and migrated.  This worked fine.

When I've pushed this out to production, I manually removed the old tables in postgresql and syncdb'ed and migrated.  However, in my admin interface a DatabaseError is raised as some function is looking for a field on the old model.  I've even dropped the entire postgresql database and syncdb'ed / migrated again and this still happens.  The offendinging field is called gender (not one that I created).  The migration works, and the database structure reflects my models, but for some reason the admin interface wants to find this (non-existant) gender field.  This is the error:

DatabaseError: column user_profiles.gender does not exist LINE 1: ... "user_profiles"."id", "user_profiles"."user_id", "user_prof...

I understand this seems to be quite site specific, but perhaps I could get some pointers on how to debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, your current code should not contain a reference to "gender" any more, since the old code was removed. Try to find a source file which still contains it:

```
find your-dir -name '*.py'|xargs grep gender
```

Or there is a pyc file, but the py file was removed. But Python still loads the pyc file....

If this does not help, please post the ascii traceback.

Comment: Thanks, this approach helped a lot.  It turns out that buried somewhere in an unused library was a module of the same name, and there was an old import statement that I had forgotten to take out (always the simplest mistakes eh!).  Hence, even though I migrated my model, the admin view was trying to find a db table for the old model. sorted.